# In systemverilog, is it possible to conditionalize a parameterized type?

Tags: system-verilog, parameterized-types

In systemverilog, can I conditionalize a parameterized type?

I want to do something like:

```
parameter IS_R = 0,
parameter type id_t = IS_R ? r_t : d_t
```

My lint program does not like this, any ideas? Is it illegal?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this. The SystemVerilog LRM only allows two operations with type parameters - assignment and equality. You could try using a `generate` construct, but the code using the conditional type has to be inside the generated block.

Comment: Dave, do you have the page# / lines in the LRM for this?

Comment: It's illegal per the BNF. See  _6.20.1 Parameter declaration syntax_ and _A.2.1.1 Module parameter declarations_